# Ordering and grouping in php/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table with `user_id` and `lap_time` and I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT `Lap`.`id`, `Lap`.`user_id`, `Lap`.`lap_time` 
FROM `laps` AS `Lap` 
WHERE `Lap`.`lap_time` < 57370 
GROUP BY `Lap`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `Lap`.`lap_time` ASC
```

I am trying to get the all the laps that are quicker than X but only unique users.

The query above doesn't return the users top lap, its like I need to order the `GROUP BY` if that makes sense?

Users can have many laps, so there could be 10 laps faster than X but they're all by same user, so I just want the top lap for that user.

Hope that makes sense and someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the fastest lap for each user_id(where lap_time is below 57370) and match it up with the correct record id. and in general, joins have a bit better performance with mysql than sub selects do.

```
select l2.id,
       l1.user_id,
       l1.lap_time
  from lap l1
  inner join lap l2
     on l1.id = l2.id
  where l1.lap_time < 57370
  group by l1.user_id
  having min(l1.lap_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you have will return every lap for every user that's lower than 57370.  <strike>If you only want each user's best lap, just add a MIN around the lap_time</strike>

```
SELECT `Lap`.`id`, `Lap`.`user_id`, min(`Lap`.`lap_time`) as `best_lap_time`
FROM `laps` AS `Lap` 
WHERE `Lap`.`lap_time` < 57370 
GROUP BY `Lap`.`user_id`
```

Also, you query formatting is pretty overkill.  No reason to make a table alias when there's only one table in the query. Unless you copy-pasted this from some program that generated it for you.

EDIT

Sorry, you are right - the min time won't always match up with the ID.  This should do the trick

```
select l.id
     , l.user_id
     , (select min(lap_time)
          from lap
         where lap_time < 57370 
           and user_id = l.user_id
       ) as best_lap_time
 group by l.user_id
having best_lap_time is not null
 order by best_lap_time asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, slight issue tho, the id thats returned is not the id of the MIN lap_time... any way round this?

Comment: I was correct, whilst this does return the lowest lap time for that user, the lap.id in the row is NOT the lap.id of the lowest lap time and I really need that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a SELECT COUNT(*) AS some_field, group by that field and use MAX to get the top-result per user.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with similar situations I've added a sub-query to ensure there isn't a faster time for that user:

`WHERE Lap.lap_time < 57370 AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from laps where laps.user_id = Lap.user_id and laps.lap_time < Lap.lap_time)`